# Centralised approach to set request timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

On my controllers actions, I can insert a `CancellationToken` parameter and the platform will fill it so I can implement cooperative cancellation. How can I configure this token? I would like to set its timeout to 10sec for example (pref in a global middleware)

Comment: The `CancellationToken` is bound to [`HttpContext.RequestAborted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestaborted?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The docs there say it's triggered *when the connection underlying this request is aborted*.

Comment: that is very helpful indeed Kirk, thank you